# How to add a new row to Smartsheet sheet with Multi-Select Dropdown values?

Tags: python-3.x, smartsheet-api

I'm building a webform that allows a user to create a new row in Smartsheet sheet. It's just a prototype at this stage but the one snag I'm running into is submitting the request where values are for a multi-select dropdown.

I've tried several things

```
#Attemp 1
new_cell.value = value
new_row.cells.append(new_cell)

#Attemp 2
multival = smart.models.MultiPicklistObjectValue()
multival.values = value
new_cell.object_value = multival
new_row.cells.append(new_cell)

#Attempt 3
multival = smart.models.MultiPicklistObjectValue()
multival.values = np.asarray(value)
new_cell.object_value = multival
new_row.cells.append(new_cell)
```

Then there's the errors...

> #Attempt 1 error: {"response": {"statusCode": 400, "reason": "Bad Request", "content": {"detail": {"index": 0}, "errorCode": 1012, "message": "Required object attribute(s) are missing from your request: cell.value.", "refId": "nbw0ymylrr19"}}}

> #Attempt 2 error: {"response": {"statusCode": 400, "reason": "Bad Request", "content": {"errorCode": 5536, "message": "The value "com.navigo.smartsheet.rest.helper.sheet.cell.model.MultiPicklist@31b27800" could not be saved in column "Audience". This column is restricted to PICKLIST values only.", "refId": "71du6l0civ0y"}}}

> #Attempt 3 error: ValueError: ("Can't load to TypedList(%s) from '%s'", <class 'str'>, array(['Clinicians', 'Chest pain committee'], dtype='<U20'))

Attempt 3 doesn't even make it past the multival.values assignment.

I've seen a lot of documents on updating rows, querying Smartsheet but I don't see a lot in the ways of Multi-Select values or adding a new row. Has anyone solved this? Or does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with the Smartsheet Python SDK, but it seems like the integration test code in the SDK's GitHub repo might be helpful. The [test_multi_picklist.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk/master/tests/integration/test_multi_picklist.py) file there contains this code that seems to match your scenario:

```
def test_add_multi_picklist_row(self, smart_setup):
        smart = smart_setup['smart']

        mplov = smartsheet.models.MultiPicklistObjectValue({
            'values': ['Bat', 'Cat']
        })

        insert_cell = smartsheet.models.Cell({
            'column_id': smart_setup['multi_picklist_col_id'],
            'object_value': mplov
        })

        row = smart.models.Row({
            'to_top': True,
            'cells': [insert_cell]
        })

        action = smart.Sheets.add_rows(smart_setup['sheet'].id, [row])
        assert action.request_response.status_code == 200
```

** **UPDATE - complete proof of concept** **

The following code uses the Smartsheet Python SDK to add a new row to a sheet (containing just 2 cells of data, for simplicity), where one of the cells belongs to a **multi-select dropdown** column in the sheet.

```
# Initialize client. 
# Uses the API token in the environment variable SMARTSHEET_ACCESS_TOKEN.
smart = smartsheet.Smartsheet()

# Define cell object (for the value in the first column) 
cell1 = smart.models.Cell({
    'column_id': 6101753539127172,
    'object_value': 'new item'
})

# Define cell object (for the value in the second column - a multi-select dropdown) 
cell2 = smart.models.Cell({
    'column_id': 8436269809198980,
    'object_value': smart.models.MultiPicklistObjectValue({'values': ['Blue', 'Green']})
})

# Create row that contains the 2 cells defined previously
row = smart.models.Row({
    'cells': [cell1, cell2]
})

# Add row to sheet
sheetId = 3932034054809476
result = smart.Sheets.add_rows(sheetId, [row])
```

Running this code successfully added the following row to my sheet (specifying 2 values for the multi-select dropdown column):

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work.  I get the error "{"response": {"statusCode": 400, "reason": "Bad Request", "content": {"detail": {"index": 0}, "errorCode": 1131, "message": "cell.objectValue for column ## was of the wrong object type. Allowed types: string, number", "refId": "1mzj98ju1bufs"}}}"

Comment: Sorry to hear you're still having trouble. If you can update your original post with the code that's returning this error, I can try to repro and troubleshoot.

Comment: @Brent - I've updated my answer to include a complete proof of concept for the scenario you've described. Hope this helps.