# Smartsheet MULTI_PICKLIST turning into TEXT_NUMER despite being level 2

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

I'm trying to populate a multi picklist with object_values, but on the older sheets it wont work as its returning `"Required object attribute(s) are missing from your request: cell.value."` So i wrote a function to update the column to a MULTI_PICKLIST, but it won't actually change

this is the code I use to update the column

```
client = smartsheet.Smartsheet('KEY')
client.errors_as_exceptions(False)

target_sheet = init_sheet(workspace, target_sheet_name, client)
target_column = target_sheet.get_colunm(1234567890)

update_column = smartsheet.models.Column({
    'title': 'New Column',
    'index': target_column.index,
    'level': 3,
    'type': 'MULTI_PICKLIST',
    'options': options
})


client.Sheets.update_column(target_sheet.id, target_column.id, update_column)
```

But when I load in the sheet again the column is still a TEXT_NUMER type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First -- the error `"Required object attribute(s) are missing from your request: cell.value."` indicates an issue with your Python code that's attempting to set values for the multi-select list. For code that shows how to create a multi-select dropdown column in a new row, see my answer on this post: [How to add a new row to Smartsheet sheet with Multi-Select Dropdown values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65135992/how-to-add-a-new-row-to-smartsheet-sheet-with-multi-select-dropdown-values). Specifically, see the code snippet in the **UPDATE - complete proof of concept** section of the answer.

Regarding the "Update Column" code you've posted in your question:

- The `index` property doesn't need to be set, since you aren't changing its value with the update column request.
- `level` is not a valid column property in an Update Column request, so setting its value is doing no good (it's just going to be ignored).

Regarding the scenario you're trying to solve for -- using an **Update Column** API request to change a column from type `TEXT_NUMBER` to type `MULTI_PICKLIST` -- seems like your code should work as written (assuming that the value of `options` in your code is a list (array) of values). (Do go ahead and remove the `index` property and `level` property though, since setting those properties in your request will have no effect.)

I proved this out by creating a `TEXT_NUMBER` column in my sheet, and then running the following code -- to change the column type to `MULTI_PICKLIST` and populate the list with 3 values.

```
column_spec = smartsheet.models.Column({
    'title': 'multi-select col now',
    'options': ['One', 'Two', 'Three'],
    'type': 'MULTI_PICKLIST'
})

# Update column
sheetId = 2702602705784708
columnId = 7331855331184516
result = smartsheet_client.Sheets.update_column(sheetId, columnId, column_spec)
```

After running this code, I verified that it worked by refreshing the sheet in Smartsheet and then looking at the column properties:

[image: col props]

So far, so good -- right? But then I issued a **Get Column** API request, to see that column definition, now that it's clearly been changed to a `MULTI_PICKLIST` column:

Request:
`GET https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/2702602705784708/columns/7331855331184516`

Here's the API response I received back:

```
{
    "id": 7331855331184516,
    "version": 2,
    "index": 4,
    "title": "multi-select col now",
    "type": "TEXT_NUMBER",
    "options": [
        "One",
        "Two",
        "Three"
    ],
    "validation": false,
    "width": 150
}
```

What the heck?! The `type` property is set to `TEXT_NUMBER` -- despite the presence of an `options` property that implies a picklist, and despite the fact that the column is definitely a `MULTI_PICKLIST` column when I look at its properties in the Smartsheet app.

I suspect that this is what you're seeing -- i.e., if you look at the column properties in the app after running your code, you'd see that the column type has indeed been changed to `MULTI_PICKLIST` -- but if you retrieve that column definition via API (either via a **Get Sheet** request or a **Get Column** request) -- the value of `column.type` in the API response is still `TEXT_NUMBER`.

Believe it or not, this behavior is actually "by design" -- due to the way that Smartsheet added/implemented the new column type `MULTI_PICKLIST` a while ago (for backwards-compatibility reasons).

- By default, API responses for `MULTI*` column types (multi-select picklists, multi-select contacts, etc.) will specify `column.type` of `TEXT_NUMBER` for
  any `MULTI*` column.
- To make an API response specify the *actual* column type for any `MULTI*` column (like `MULTI_PICKLIST`, for example) -- the corresponding API request must specify the `level` query string parameter, with value set as described here (taken from the docs for the [Get Column](https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/tag/columns#operation/column-get) operation).

[image: level param]

So, if I issue another **Get Column** request for my column -- this time specifying `level=2` in the query string -- I see that the value returned for `type` is `MULTI_PICKLIST`, as I expect it to be.

Request:
`GET https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/2702602705784708/columns/7331855331184516?level=2`

Response:

```
{
    "id": 7331855331184516,
    "version": 2,
    "index": 4,
    "title": "multi-select col now",
    "type": "MULTI_PICKLIST",
    "options": [
        "One",
        "Two",
        "Three"
    ],
    "validation": false,
    "width": 150
}
```